# How to increase the max request header in the Loadbalancer(Keepalived) & kubernetes APP Docker Container

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, keepalived

I have a K8s Cluster build on v1.8 with HA mode having keepalived & nginx as a LB.I want to increase the max request header to 64MB at the LB Proxy level. Can any one suggest on how to increase the max request header at the proxy level & Docker container level?

### keepalived Configuration:

```
    vrrp_instance VI_PUB {
    interface ens32
    mcast_src_ip 172.16.x.x
    virtual_router_id x
    priority x
    virtual_ipaddress {
    172.16.x.x
    }
    }
    virtual_server 172.16.x.x 9081  {
    quorum_down /etc/keepalived/stop_keepalived.sh
    delay_loop 15
    lb_algo wrr
    lb_kind NAT
    protocol TCP
    real_server 172.16.x.x 8081 {
    TCP_CHECK {
     connect_timeout 3
    nb_get_retry 2
    delay_before_retry 1
    }
    }
    }
```

If you want any more details - please let me know I'll update the Body accordingly..

Comment: are you using Nginx Ingress?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov - no, I'm not using that.

Comment: please open the ticket on keepalived [github repository](https://github.com/acassen/keepalived)